# Prevent Java from loading library more than once

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have several classes that use the same JNI library, called "jni". In each of those classes, I have a System.loadLibrary() call in the class's static initializer:

```
Class class1 {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("jni");
    }
    ...
}

Class class2 {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("jni");
    }
    ...
}
```

The only problem is, I only want System.loadLibrary() to be called once, since it can take a while. Is there an easy and clean way to prevent multiple loadings of the same library?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the library has already be loaded any subsequent calls to load the same library will be ignored.

[`System.loadLibrary`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)):

> Loads the system library specified by
>   the libname  argument. The manner in
>   which a library name is mapped to the
>   actual system library is system
>   dependent.
>
> The call System.loadLibrary(name) is
>   effectively equivalent to the call
>
> ```
>  Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(name)
> ```

[`Runtime.loadLibrary`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)):

> Loads the dynamic library with the
>   specified library name. A file
>   containing native code is loaded from
>   the local file system from a place
>   where library files are conventionally
>   obtained. The details of this process
>   are implementation-dependent. The
>   mapping from a library name to a
>   specific filename is done in a
>   system-specific manner.
>
> First, if there is a security manager,
>   its checkLink method is called with
>   the libname as its argument. This may
>   result in a security exception.
>
> The method System.loadLibrary(String)
>   is the conventional and convenient
>   means of invoking this method. If
>   native methods are to be used in the
>   implementation of a class, a standard
>   strategy is to put the native code in
>   a library file (call it LibFile) and
>   then to put a static initializer:
>
> ```
>  static { System.loadLibrary("LibFile"); }
> ```
>
> within the class declaration. When the
>   class is loaded and initialized, the
>   necessary native code implementation
>   for the native methods will then be
>   loaded as well.
>
> ***If this method is called more than
>   once with the same library name, the
>   second and subsequent calls are
>   ignored.***

Comment: Is this true for System.load too? The docs don't specify either way.

Comment: Yes. This is true for System.load too.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) -

> If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure any subsequent calls to load an already loaded library have no effect [citation needed].

This was verified in the `ClassLoader` class source code, but I'm still trying to find a good source for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class which load "jni" only during it's first instantiation, and call this singleton in class1 and class2 instead of System.loadLibrary("jni")