# JNI load library more than once

Tags: java, java-native-interface

as mentioned here
[Prevent Java from loading library more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133083/prevent-java-from-loading-library-more-than-once)
a library only gets loaded once.

Now my problem is, that I want to load the same libray explizitly more than once. (The System.load command does the same as the loadlibrary command).

Any idea which command I can use, or how I could do that?

Best Regards, 
Stefan

Comment: Could you explain why you want to load it more than once, and what you expect the effect of loading it more than once to be?

Comment: I could, but that wouldn't help much. Basically each libray has his own set of objects, which it sould store.... and no I cant really change the C++ code to manga it, I really have to load the same library more than once!!!

Comment: sorry if that sounds rude... :(, but the dll was designe so small to be loaded multiple times, so that loadLibrary only loads it once is really a problem.........

Comment: Nope - not rude, don't worry. I think you are facing a dead end here. As fas as I know, the library is loaded to an instance of a classloader, so unless you can do something complicated with the classloading, I don't see a resolution within the java layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is not so much a Java limitation as the design of most operating systems. In my experience, Windows/Linux/Solaris do not allow loading the same library more than once. You may need to modify the C++ that you don't want to modify. If you don't have control of that code you may have to work on a different solution involving executing/spawning a new process for each copy of the DLL you want to load and communicating via pipes/sockets.

Answer (score 1):

thanks basszero for the answer, I really have to start new processes if I want to load the same dll muliple times. My approche to do this now is to have

- one main class which spanns new processes
- one class which loads the dlls

The technique to do this is the ProcessBuilder. Here is a small coding example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "java", "Mainclass");
String filepath = "C:\\{..}\\bin\\";
File directory = new File(filepath);
pb.directory(directory);
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    InputStream is =  p.getInputStream();
    int c;
    while((c = is.read()) != -1){
        sb.append((char)c);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This of course will be allot of work since I somehow have to exchange the objects between the processes, synchronize them, etc...... :-(

If anywone sees this exampe I would suggest to him, that he edits his C++, which is sadly not possible in my case.

Regards,
Stefan