# Java/JNI - UnsatisfiedLinkError when finding class in JNI_OnLoad

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have the following classes:

NativeClass.java

```
public class NativeClass {

    public static final int CONSTANT_VALUE = getValue();

    public static native int getValue();

}
```

TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
        System.out.println(NativeClass.CONSTANT_VALUE);
    }

}
```

C code:

```
#include <jni.h>

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    (*env)->FindClass(env, "LNativeClass;");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeClass_getValue(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    return 5;
}
```

I compiled the C file like this:

```
gcc NativeClass.c -I"JNI_HEADER_PATH" -shared -fPIC -o libnative.so
```

And execute the code like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. TestClass
```

I then get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NativeClass.getValue()I
```

If I move the `System.loadLibrary("native");` to a static intializer block in `NativeClass` it works just fine:

```
public class NativeClass {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static final int CONSTANT_VALUE = getValue();

    public static native int getValue();

}
```

What am I missing here?
The code here is just an example of the exact error I'm having in a project.
I absolutely have to need the constant to be declared in `NativeClass` and I also need to find the class in JNI_OnLoad because I have to call a static method in it.

Comment: So, what is wrong in keeping `loadLibrary()` in static constructor?

Comment: I need to load the library in `TestClass`, not in `NativeClass`. This is just an example. In reality, there are many classes with native functionality. `NativeClass` is the only class that needs to be accessed in `JNI_OnLoad`. Previously, all files were compiled into a single library, which is loaded in another class, but now I separated the functionality of `NativeClass` into a separate library which is loaded in the static initializer of `NativeClass`. I'd like to compile everything into only one library though.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is that you cannot load same library from different static constructors. But why? See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133100/192373)

Answer (score 0):

`main` is part of `TestClass` and can't be called until `TestClass` is loaded.  But `TestClass` can't be loaded until `System.loadLibrary("native");` is called.

So this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary("native");
```

can never be called - calling `main` depends on the class being loaded which depends on `loadLibrary` being called which depends on `main` being called....

Comment: `TestClass` is loaded though, if I print something out before loading the library in `TestClass`, it gets printed.