# Android NDK making library available all through the app

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am diving into the ndk stuff and I've managed to make a simple library and call it from my activity.

In order to test it, in my `Activity` I have used:

```
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("my-lib");
    }

    public native static String callNativeFunction(Context context);
```

This means that calling `MyActivity.callNativeFunction(context)` does return the `String` value from my Cpp function.

I have 2 questions:

1. The `loadLibrary` is made in my main activity, however I want to be able for instance, to call the `callNativeFunction` function from an `IntentService` when the activity may be closed or from other places of my app. How can I properly load the library and have it available from all places of the app?
2. Since this is a simple function that I'll use in my project, is there anything else specific to do on release? From https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html it seems that Gradle builds for all supported abis and adds them into the apk.

Comment: ad1: the same way you do in your activity ad2: `externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }` (if you are using cmake of course)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to load the library once. This can also be done in your `Application` class. Once the library is loaded, you can call the defined native methods from the appropriate classes defined in your `cpp` class

Application class :

```
public class SRApplication extends Application {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("my-lib");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

CPP :

```
extern "C"
jstring
Java_com_example_service_ExampleService_getNativeString (
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject /* this */) {

    return env->NewStringUTF("yo");
}
```

Your Service :

```
package com.example.service.ExampleService;

public class ExampleService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        String nativeString = getNativeString();
        return null;
    }

    public native String getNativeString();

}
```

2. If you don't have specific code for different cpu variants, you don't need to explicitly handle anything, the default

   `externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           cppFlags ""
       }
   }`

   is sufficient.

Comment: added code snippet. hope that gives you a better idea.

Comment: Can I in `SRApplication` add `public native static String callNativeFunction(Context context);` and then from either my activity or service simply call `SRApplication.getNativeString()` without the need to add `public native String getNativeString()` in Activity/Service? For instance, I may need to call it from a Class, which is not part of a service or activity. Thank you

Comment: Yes that is also possible.

Comment: too much hassle for a custom `Application`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133100/2252830)